# Firefox 403 on Fonts on CodeIgniter Site

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, firefox, http-status-code-403

I am using font-face in CSS to import custom fonts on to a web application that I'm building using CodeIgniter. Here's the CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'UniversLT-UltraCondensed';
    src: url('../Fonts/LTUnivers/universlt59ultracondensed.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/LTUnivers/universlt59ultracondensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/LTUnivers/universlt59ultracondensed.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/LTUnivers/universlt59ultracondensed.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/LTUnivers/universlt59ultracondensed.svg#universlt59ultracondensed') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    font-family: UniversLT-UltraCondensed, Helvetica, Arial, serif;
}
```

When I run the site in Safari, Chrome or Opera the fonts are loaded correctly. When I run it in FireFox I get the following:

[image: 403]

A 403 error suggests to me I have got the server configuration wrong or the .htaccess file wrong somehow. I'm a newb when it comes to that stuff, but here's what's in my .htaccess (assuming that is the problem...):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Tat
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Tat/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|fonts|woff|ttf|svg|eot)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Tat/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /Tat/index.php
</IfModule>
```

It should also be noted that these files have 777 permission (I have SSH access to the server running Ubuntu Lucid).

Any suggestions? I haven't a clue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, found the problem. I have been working for hours on this and as soon as I post I fix it, typical!

Anyway, for anyone else that may have similar problems - the issue was that I had set the permissions in Linux on the development virtual server but not on Mac OSX on the folder that is mounted by the VM. So I opened terminal and chmod -R 777'd the fonts folder and it seemed to work.

Comment: Wouldn't `644` work just as well? Seems like fonts shouldn't need execute permission.

Comment: Yeh guess so, I'm a noob with permissions etc, when I deploy to the production server I'll look into things properly